# Cannot store JSON data to local storage from dynamic list, Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I am trying to save into localstorage data that have been populated from an external json file as "favorites".
Specifically,

I have a listview in Jquery mobile 1.4.5 that when clicked each item creates a dynamic page.
Now I want that page to be able to be saved as a favorite for later use.

My code so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="ccc">
 <div data-role="header">
    <h1>My page</h1> 
</div>  
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <ul id="mylist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">

    </ul>

</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
    $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#ccc", function () {    

$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4khhg', function(data) {
        var output="";
        var newpage="";
        for (var i in data.mydata) {
            output+="<li>" + 
            "<a href=\"#page" + data.mydata[i].myId + "\">" + 
            "<h3>" + data.mydata[i].thename + "</h3>" +
            "<p>" + data.mydata[i].desciption + "</p>" + "</a>" +
            "</li>";

            //see if page already exists in DOM
            if ($("#page" + data.mydata[i].myId).length == 0) {
                newpage+="<div data-role=\"page\" id=\"page" + data.mydata[i].myId + "\">";
                newpage+="<div data-role=\"header\">"+
                "<a data-role=\"button\"  data-rel=\"back\" data-icon=\"back\">Back</a>" +"<h3>" +
                data.mydata[i].thename +  "</h3>" + 
"<a data-role=\"button\"  data-icon=\"star\"   class=\"saveit\"  data-saveid=\"" +     data.mydata[i].myId +
                    "\">Save it button</a>" + "</div>";
          newpage+="<div role=\"main\" class=\"ui-content\">" + 
          data.mydata[i].desciption +  "</div> </div>";
            }

        }

      output+="";
      newpage += "";
      $('body').append(newpage);
      $("#mylist").html(output).listview('refresh');
////////////////// start save function ///////////////    
$(".saveit").click(function (){
var saveditems = [];
saveditems[0] = "<h3>  " + data.mydata[i].thename + "</h3>  " +  data.mydata[i].desciption ;
localStorage["saveditems"] = JSON.stringify(saveditems);
var storeditemss = JSON.parse(localStorage["saveditems"]);
    alert(saveditems);

});
////////////////// end save function ///////////////

});
});
```

**[A fiddle code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/twjjL53r/9/)**

My main problems are:

1. The function is called as it seems many times ( I have an alert) as
   we click three - four times the button "Save it". The more times we
   go back to the list and then re-open the dynamic pages, the more
   times the function is called.
2. The main problem is that the current item in the loop is not saved in localstorage. Only the last item of the loop.

Any help or hints?

thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems.

Your click handler is being added to the same class each time the form is show. That is why your are getting multiple alerts after going back and forth.  Use event delegation instead to create the handler one on pagecreate:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#ccc", function () {    
    $(document).on("click", ".saveit", function (){
      var saveditems = JSON.parse(localStorage["saveditems"]) || [];

      var s = '<h3>' +  $(this).parent(".ui-header").find("h3").text() +'</h3>' + $(this).parents(".ui-page").find(".ui-content").text()
      saveditems.push(s);
      localStorage["saveditems"] = JSON.stringify(saveditems);
      var storeditemss = JSON.parse(localStorage["saveditems"]);
      alert(saveditems);            
});
```

In the handler you were trying to use the variable i which is part of the loop. Instead, on click you need to get the info from the page the button is on. (You could also use data-attributes on the button itself).

Finally, as saveditems is an array, don't keep overwriting saveditems[0]. Instead use push() to keep adding entries. You will also need to add checks for whether the item is already in the favorites list...

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/twjjL53r/10/)**

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.  Isn't any  other way to add the current data.mydata[i].thename and data.mydata[i].desciption variables into the localstorage without the find function?

Comment: @qwertyg, sure, you could add them as data attributes of the button. Or you could maintain the mydata array as a global variable on the page and get the appropriate entry by ID or index stored with the button. There are many ways...

Comment: thank you. Can you pls elaborate more on the mydata array as a global variable in this example? how can I retrieve its data by id via the button?

Comment: This is excellent, and very good example. Thank you very much